# dynamic url in REST post

Tags: java, rest, post

I am developing a rest webservice
my @RequestMapping is like /{bookId}/list

How do I pass the book Id in the request
I am trying
//localhost:80003/123/list but its not working

What should I make sure so that I can pass dynamic values in request URL for a res service

Thanks

Comment: You are connecting to localhost:80003, where port 80003 is out of port range. (Max is 65535)

Also we need more information about what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you entered one too many zeros in your port since 80003 is not valid.
Anyway, you can use @PathVariable like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{bookId}/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Video getId(@PathVariable("bookId") long id) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to do @RequestMapping(value = "/{bookId}/list/{shelfId}"

Cant I send 2 dynamic values. I corrected the number of zeroes in 80003 and it worked (Thanks/. :)). But its not working for 2 dynamic values.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351015/multiple-pathvariable-in-spring-mvc