# Spring Data JPA : retrieve data with multiple @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve a user's **particular** order.

---

This is how I retrieve the user's order**s** in my OrderController

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/orders")
public List<Order> findAll(@PathVariable Long id) throws UserNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> existingUser = this.userRepository.findById(id);

    if (existingUser.isEmpty()) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    return existingUser.get().getOrders();
}
```

With the RequestMapping

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class OrderController {(...)}
```

---

This is the OneToMany relationship

User Entity

```
// ONE TO MANY
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Order> orders;
```

Order Entity

```
// MANY TO ONE
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;
```

---

The UserRepository and OrderRepository interface, both extend JpaRepository

---

I do manage to retrieve all the user's orders through Postman

[image]

---

I am now wondering, how can I retrieve a user's particular order?

So for instance,
as shown in the image let's say I would only like to retrieve the order with the id of 2, in this particular address :

```
http://localhost:8070/api/users/1/orders/2
```

How can I make it please ?

Comment: Did you try this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351015/multiple-pathvariable-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an endpoint with

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/orders/{orderId}")
```

and return the particular order.

Create an OrderRepository and simply create the

```
public Order findByIdAndUserId(long orderId,long userId);
```

interface method for retrieving the given one.

Just a remark: you should validate that the given user is the same as the logged in one. What happen if I send a request to the backend, where I rewrite the user id to someone else's id?

Comment: Oh indeed I haven't thought about this..
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    @GetMapping("/{userId}/orders/{orderId}")
    public Order findAll(@PathVariable Long userId, @PathVariable Long orderId) throws Exception {
        //your code
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was actually wondering how to solve it through the repository, but you helped me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you should had a Get mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}/orders/{orderId}")
public List<Order> findAll(@PathVariable Long userId, @PathVariable Long orderId) throws UserNotFoundException {
    ...
}
```

And for the requesting, you have three options:

1. Call you `this.userRepository.findById(id)` and filter after your order.
2. Create an OrderRepository to limit the request to the order table. But you need to have a reference to the user and you will probably not improve any performance. I would not advise that.
3. Add a query in your order repository to query the orderId for the userId:

---

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<.., ..> {
    @Query("select ... from User user join user.orders ... where ...user = :userId and order = :orderId")
    Order getUserOrder(@Param("userId") String userId, @Param("orderId") String orderId);
}
```

Anyway, You should create a service and inject it in the controller to encapsulate the search/filtering complexity and let you endpoints code clean (`@Autowired private OrderService orderService`):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;
}
```

and:

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

}
```